# ¿Como crear una card con una imagen de fondo con opacidad del 10%?

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando crear una card de boostrap cuyo fondo sea una imagen que ocupe el 100% y sea casi transparente sin que afecte el resto de elementos. De momento no lo he logrado.

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 h-100">
      <div class="card-body undefined">
         <div>
            <img src="http://mi.imagen.local/bg.jpg" alt="Card image" class="bg-img"> 
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column mb-5">
               <img src="logo.jpg" class="my-4" style="max-width: 350px;"> 
               <h4>Crear cuenta</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                  <form> Here all my code </form>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

También he intentado añadir la imagen como background del div y no funciona (afecta al resto de elementos)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que hice fue crear un nuevo `div` adentro del `card-body` y justo antes del `div` que encierra a todo el contenido de tu `card`:

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid p-4">
  <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 h-100">
    <div class="card-body undefined">
      <div class="fondo"></div> <!-- este div lo creo -->
      <div>
      <!-- aquí va el contenido de tu card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y a la clase del nuevo `div`, llamado `fondo`, le di las siguientes propiedades:

```
.fondo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

En donde:

- **`position: absolute`**: La posición del elemento será absoluta y cubrirá todo el card.
- **`background-image`**: Será la imagen que ocupará el fondo del elemento.
- **`background-repeat: no-repeat`**: Indico que la imagen no se repetirá.
- **`background-size: cover`**: Renderizo la imagen para que ocupe el tamaño del card.
- **`opacity: 0.3`**: Le aplico opacidad a la imagen.
- **`z-index: -1`**: El elemento estará detrás del todo.

---

En resumen, estoy creando un nuevo `div`, en donde este `div` ocupará todo el `card`. También tendrá una imagen de fondo, una opacidad y su ubicación estará atrás del todo para que la opacidad no afecte al contenido del `card`.

PSDT: Cuando estamos ubicándolo detrás del todo al elemento con la imagen, ese elemento lo podremos ver gracias a la clase `bg-transparent` que tiene el `card`, ya que con esto indicamos que el `background` del `card` es transparente, y dicho a esto, podemos ver lo que hay detrás de él (o sea, vemos el elemento con la imagen).

---

Código completo:

```css
.fondo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app" class="container-fluid p-4">
  <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 h-100">
    <div class="card-body undefined">
      <div class="fondo"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column mb-5">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" class="my-4" style="max-width: 50%;"> 
          <h4>Crear cuenta</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
            <form> Here all my code </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/VwGZGGo).